# Will Auto Layout Be Required on iOS 13?

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, storyboard, ios13

I am maintaining an older Objective-C app which does not use auto layout in its storyboards. I noticed that the "Use Auto Layout" checkbox on the file inspector has been removed when working in iOS13 (Using Xcode 11 beta 6). Does this mean I need to update all of the existing storyboards to use auto layout and constraints?

The app still runs without changes to the storyboards, but warnings and errors such as: missing constraints, ambiguous content size, and localization issues now appear when viewing many view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

auto layout is going to be pushed a lot in Xcode 11, I've noticed that myself. however, you can try using xib files instead and use basic constraints and use "add missing constraints" in the all new section.